# angularjs $http : sending special characters in path param

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am trying to invoke a REST service which has a special character in its path params. The rest url looks like,

```
rest\fetchDetails\[1,2,3]
```

I am just invoking it using $http like,

```
$http.get('rest\fetchDetails\[1,2,3]');
```

It is not working and when I debug it using firebug I can see the url is sent as

```
rest\fetchDetails\%5B1,2,3%5D
```

Is there any way to send '[' and ']' when invoking $http calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Try with post request and pass params in Post Request.

**Solution 2:**

'[]' are special characters for URL. So it will be encoded.

If you want to decode this are your server code you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually sending '[' and ']', however they are being [url-encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) by the `$http.get` method. The url-encoding is necessary because the HTTP standard only allows some characters (alpha-numeric plus some) to be sent non-url-encoded.

BTW, I assume the backslashes () in your URL are regular slashes (/) since otherwise they too would be url-encoded.